# how to setup Teamcity (2021.2.2) deploy app with clickonce

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, teamcity, cicd

I have a simple wpf/console app build that I want to deploy and be able to update where ever it is installed. So I picked clickonce, from ms, because that seamed to fit my needs.

I can build, deploy, install and update it manually quite fine ;-) but when I move to do the same steps on my teamcity build server, i ran into trouble.

I have a very simpel pipeline.

1. build the app (works fine)
2. make the setup.exe, to be installed.. <= trouble !!
3. copy to an ISS hosted website.

ad 1) my build:
[image]

ad 2) my make click once....
[image]

If I run through step 2 manually in visual studio on the buildserver, it works. I get the binaries published in a folder. That I can copy to the IIS folder. but nothing is produced with TeamCity !!!

- what am I doing wrong?
  (the trace looks like there are no files, to work with. they are gone somehow...)

8x--------
lines pasted in from teamcity log

```
in directory: C:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\4c50753a43ea36fe
```

17:14:49     Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET

17:14:49     Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

17:14:49

17:14:50     Build started 27/01/2022 17.14.50.

17:14:50          0>Process = "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"

17:14:50            MSBuild executable path = "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.404\MSBuild.dll"

17:14:50            Command line arguments = ""C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.404\MSBuild.dll" -maxcpucount -verbosity:m -target:Publish -property:TargetFramework=net5.0 -property:Configuration=Release -property:VersionSuffix=187 -property:NoBuild=true C:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\4c50753a43ea36fe\TeamCityNugetTest.sln @C:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\temp\agentTmp\2.rsp"

17:14:50            Current directory = "C:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\4c50753a43ea36fe"

17:14:50            MSBuild version = "16.11.2+f32259642"

17:14:50     Project "TeamCityNugetTest.sln": Publish

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you define your output directory to a location outside of:

```
C:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\4c50753a43ea36fe
```

I assume TeamCity is trying to put the outputs in `\bin`, as happens on a normal build/publish, unless you specify the output elsewhere. And if your repository doesn't contain `\bin`, it won't have an actual place to put it when it's done.

Also, you could probably just do the second build step. I believe `dotnet publish` will build the project/solution anyway.

Comment: While it's possible to combine build and publish, I prefer not to publish artifacts that haven't passed unit testing, so I generally separate out all the operations as separate build steps. It's also a bit easier to see what's failing when it fails.